# Turns in solenoid coil or coilgun

Tags: coil, solenoid

more turns = increase in wire length = increase in resistance = decrease in current

So how come more coil turns will increase the strength of electromagnetic field?

Comment: well, (1) but the relationship is not linear, (2) And you can have longer but thicker wire etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *So how come more coil turns will increase the strength of electromagnetic field*

For a solenoid or electromagnet, more field strength means more magnetic force of attraction. We can use that relationship in this formula: -

$$\text{Force} = \dfrac{(\text{Current}\cdot \text{turns})^2\cdot \mu_0\cdot A}{2\cdot g^2}$$

Where

- A is cross sectional area of the electromagnet
- g is gap to your magnet
- \$\mu_0\$ is 4\$\pi\$ x \$10^{-7}\$

So, if you double the turns you get 4 times the magnetic attraction force due to that factor alone. However, if you double the turns and the resistance of the wire is a significant limiting factor, then, the current available halves and this cancels out the gains from doubling the turns.

In different circumstances, the wire resistance may not be a significant limiting factor.

Answer (score 4):

Keeping the important things equal, the number of turns are irrelevant.

The important things are

- mass of copper
- applied power

This is quite easy to see if you consider a solenoid wound with a number of turns of bifilar (two strands, side by side) wire, with the same current flowing through each strand.

If you connect the windings in series, you'll have twice the turns on the solenoid, and double the applied voltage. If you connect them in parallel, you'll have double the wire area, and double the applied current.

The important things are the same - same mass of copper, same ampere-turns so same magnetic field, same total power requirements.

However, when we say we 'add turns' to a solenoid, we often are not keeping the important things equal. If we increase the amount of copper by adding more turns of the same wire, then the magnet gets bigger and more efficient. If we increase the resistance without increasing the applied voltage, we decrease the power.

The question as asked has too many undefined variables.

Define what things you are keeping equal, power supply voltage, current, total power, mass of copper, compute the current and ampere-turns properly, and then your question will answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

With "some" assumptions (force calculus), one might consider this (theoretical).

One can see that Force F is proportional to \$N^2/gap\$ ...
NB: forget the spring ...

[image]